# How do I create a single-value field in Solr/Solarium?

Tags: php, solr, solarium

I've done a vanilla install of Solr and Solarium for PHP

Solarium 5.x
PHP 7.1
Solr 8.5.1

I can create and query documents.  But all fields I create are returned as arrays - except for "id". obviously there is some schema somewhere that specifies that id is a single-value field.  how can I create my own single-value fields?  All fields I create are multi-value arrays.

The multi-value field feature is useful but there are only a few cases where I will need it.

It seems I should be able to define the field types and specify whether they are multi-value or not but instead all fields I create are multi-value arrays and I can't appear to change that.  the solarium documentation has a section on multi-value fields but not single-value fields.

https://solarium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/documents/#multivalue-fields

I don't see any documentation in solarium for defining the documents and their field types.  possibly something is wrong with my installation.

here is my code example:

```
$client = new Solarium\Client($config);

// get an update query instance
$update = $client->createUpdate();

// create a new document for the data
$doc1 = $update->createDocument();
// add data to the document
$doc1->id       = 123; // single value by default
$doc1->name     = 'document name'; // always results in an array
$doc1->price    = 5; // always results in an array


// add the documents and a commit command to the update query
$update->addDocuments(array($doc1));
$update->addCommit();

// this executes the query and returns the result
$result = $client->update($update);

// then query the documents
$query = $client->createSelect();
$query->setQuery('*:*');
$resultSet = $client->select($query);

echo 'NumFound: '.$resultSet->getNumFound().'<br>';
foreach ($resultSet as $document) {
    foreach ($document as $field => $value) {
        // I can test to see if $value is an array but my point is that I don't want
        // to do so for every single field.  how can I define fields that are single-value by default?
        echo '<div'> . $field . ' : ' . $value . '</div>';
    }
}
```

this outputs:

NumFound: 1
id : 123
name : Array
price : Array

yes I know how to get those values out of the array but I know there must be some way to get single-value fields by default.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that I can define multiValued="false", and many other detailed properties of a field, by manually editing managed-schema (schema.xml) in the conf directory for the core.

however it says at the top of this file:

So now the real question is, how do you edit the SOLR schema?